# Always show height scrollbar within the viewport of the parent div

Tags: css, sass, scrollbar, viewport, react-table

I use React-Table as a table component. Within there, I'm basically presented with the following scenario: https://codesandbox.io/s/52lvxrj8r4

The vertical scrollbar of the body is doing its thing, however, it's outside of the viewport of the parent div, which does the horizontal scrolling. Meaning you only see the vertical scrollbar when you completely scroll the horizontal scrollbar to the right.

My html is:

```html
<div class="rt-table">
   <div class="rt-tbody">
      test
      <br />
      test
      <br />
      (repeat test<br /> many times)
   </div>
</div>
```

My SASS is:

```
.rt-table {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  .rt-tbody {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

Is there a possibility to make sure that the vertical scrollbar is always shown within the viewport of its parent, regardless of the position of the horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

Change your sass as to put the scrolling on the parent and not on the child.

When creating a scrollable container always make sure the smaller outer container is the one that contains the scrollbars, otherwise your scrollbars might be hidden.

```
.rt-table {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  .rt-tbody {
    height: auto;
    width: 1000px;   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't fix it, because `.rt-table` shouldn't scroll vertically, because the headers of the table are sticky. That's the problem. The scrollbar of the child div must always be visible in the parent viewport.